# How to get the href value and use it as the id of a target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the existing href value as my target in manipulating the css. Unfortunately, I can't seem to make it work. I need a little assistance where did I go wrong.

```js
$(function(){

    $('.tab-items a').each(function(){
    
        var target_ids = $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase();;
    
        var target_image =$(target_ids).find('a:first img').attr('src');
        
        $(this).css('background' 'url("'+ target_image +'")');
        
    })

})
```

```css
.tab-items a { 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-items">
    <li>
        <a href="#nature_231">Nature</a>
        <a href="#people_541">People</a>        
        <a href="#people_961">Animals</a>                
    </li>
    
</ul>

<div>
    <div id="nature_231">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/1" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/2" alt="" /></a>            
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/3" alt="" /></a>        
    </div>

    <div id="#people_541">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/1" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/2" alt="" /></a>            
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/3" alt="" /></a>        
    </div>

    <div id="#animals_961">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/1" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/2" alt="" /></a>            
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/3" alt="" /></a>        
    </div>    
    
    
    
</div>
```

Comment: Missing a comma in your `.css` call: `.css("background", "url...")`

Comment: Next time, check the console. It's there for a reason!

Comment: Console wont bring him error if it becomes a valid property name when comma missing ;) @NiettheDarkAbsol but you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See out put ,Working Fine

You are missing comma separator in argument to css()

```js
$(function(){

    $('.tab-items a').each(function(){
    
        var target_ids = $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase();;
    console.log(target_ids)
        var target_image =$(target_ids).find('a:first img').attr('src');
        
       console.log(target_image)
        $(this).css('background', 'url("'+ target_image +'")');
        
    })

})
```

```css
.tab-items a { 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-items">
    <li>
        <a href="#nature_231">Nature</a>
        <a href="#people_541">People</a>        
        <a href="#people_961">Animals</a>                
    </li>
    
</ul>

<div>
    <div id="nature_231">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/1" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/2" alt="" /></a>            
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/3" alt="" /></a>        
    </div>

    <div id="#people_541">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/1" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/2" alt="" /></a>            
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/3" alt="" /></a>        
    </div>

  

 <div id="#animals_961">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/1" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/2" alt="" /></a>            
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/3" alt="" /></a>        
    </div>    
    
    
    
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

IDK about JQuery, 
But in Javascript, I would just iterate through an array of 'a' tags searching for the proper href, like this, you could even make it a function to ID your href:

```
var matchHref = function(input) {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), href, target;

    for(var i = 0, j = a.length; i < j; ++i) {
        href = a[i].getAttribute('href');
        if(href === input){
            target = a[i];
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Then you could just do this to call it:

```
matchHref('href-name').style.whatever-you-change;
```